# Preview the picture below the picture on mouse over but only in small circle like a magnifying glass

Tags: html, css, angular, image, animation

I have pictures of the device on technical drawing and I want to see this drawing below only in small circle. I dont know how to settle ten effect. Something like this:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_image_magnifier_glass.asp

but I do not want to enlarge but to show the part of the picture which is under this picture.
Im using Angular 8+ html css bootstrap and Angular Material

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=angular+preview+image+magnifying+glass++site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: I found an answer just by searching "angular+preview+image+magnifying+glass" and found one with the exact same w3fools link - next time please try the same before asking

Comment: but this is magnifying glass. I don't want to enlarge the picture

Comment: Then remove the magnification. The rest of the code will be the same

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still don't know how to see another picture in this circle?

Comment: If you clone this https://angular-w3school-image-magnification-9wmezt.stackblitz.io  - you just have to figure out how to darken what is not under the cursor